# How to find the "interior boundary" for a set of points?

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, polyhedra, mobius-transformation, polytopes

Let $S$ be a set of points in $\mathbf{R}^n$:

$$S=\{ (x_1,\dots,x_n) \ | \ x_i \in \mathbf{R} \ ; i=1,\dots, n \}$$

Is there a way to find the interior boundary of such set of points?

Since there is an efficient way to find the [exterior boundary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/finding-boundary-co-ordinates-from-given-set-of-point-co-ordinates) or the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a set of points. I would expect to have a similar way to find the "interior hull" / "interior boundary".

It seems like some [kernel transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) to higher dimension, Mobious transformation or Inclusion Exclusion Principle might help here, though I am not sure how to use any of them.

---

**Clarification**: 
Convex Hull gives the minimal convex polytope $P$ s.t. $S \subseteq P$. I am looking for a polytope $P'$ with the maximum volume such that $O$ is in its volume and $S \cap P' = \emptyset $.

We say that a point is contained in a polytope's volume if there exists an infinitesimal ball around the point s.t. $B_\epsilon \subset P$.

---

If finding the polytope is hard what about finding the largest ellipsoid rather than polytope?

Comment: Remove the boundary points and compute boundary again? By the way, how come the point counterclowise of the point next to the B in Boundary is a boundary point and not an interior boundary point?

Comment: Do you have a mathematical definition of this "interior boundary"? One picture alone does not communicate what you mean in general.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, given an origin $O$ this will be the closest boundary. I am not sure how to define it rigorously.

Comment: @orole it's a boundary inspired by [Matlab's `boundary` shrinking factor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html).

Comment: Perhaps perform an [inversion in a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) centred on $O$, then apply whatever your outer boundary algorithm is?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, sounds smart, can you help me to formulate it and to prove it actually gives the right result?

Comment: I can't prove it gives the right result without a rigorous definition of what the right result is!

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, that's also what I meant how can we define the interior  boundary properly? Given an origin $O$ and a set of points with distance greater than 0 from $O$, the interior boundary would be the closest boundary of the points that are closest to $O$ where the boundary is a valid boundary.

Comment: The problem is that it is not clear what a "valid boundary" is. There is no standard notion of this. Since you don't have a clear definition in mind a priori, why don't you just try Anthony's suggestion and see if it works for you in practice?

Comment: @Rahul the thing is that if I find the boundary after the transformation how do I convert it back? I know it's geometric projection that preserves geometry, but still I am not sure. It sounds like it should work though.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, please see the definition I added.

Comment: OK, your definition seems sensible, but doesn't agree with your picture: e.g. you could include two more points to the left. My proposed procedure does not produce this result, since circle inversion does not preserve straight lines. (Intuitively I don't think there is any geometric transformation that reduces this to the convex hull - the behaviour of straight lines near infinity is very different to that of straight lines near zero.) My suggestion would be a direct computational approach, perhaps trying to adapt one of the well-known efficient algorithms for the usual convex hull.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis can I define it as a linear programming or optimization problem?